# Improving speed with Cython when dealing with Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm testing Cython performance when a numpy ndarray is changed based on whether the sum of the i-th and j-th indices are even or odd. Compared to Python, the Cython speed is merely 80% faster, which is somewhat of a mediocre gain in speed. I've ran out of ideas at the moment. Any suggestions?

@Python:

```
def even_odd_function(matrix):

    dim = matrix.shape[1]

    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
                matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, j] ** 2
            else:
                matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, j] * -1

    return matrix
```

@Cython:

```
%%cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def even_odd_function7(np.ndarray matrix):

    cdef int dim = matrix.shape[1]
    cdef int i
    cdef int j

    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
                matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, j] * matrix[i, j]
            else:
                matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, j] * -1

    return matrix
```

Here are the highlighted lines:
 [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to annotate the type of your array for the major speedup.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def even_odd_function8(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] matrix):

    cdef int dim = matrix.shape[1]
    cdef int i
    cdef int j

    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
                matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, j] * matrix[i, j]
            else:
                matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, j] * -1

    return matrix

In [20]: arr = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)

In [21]: %timeit even_odd_function(arr)
1 loop, best of 3: 636 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit even_odd_function7(arr)
1 loop, best of 3: 480 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit even_odd_function8(arr)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 ms per loop
```

Largely a stylistic thing, but I prefer the newer typed memoryview syntax, which will do the same thing.

```
def even_odd_function(np.float64_t[:,:] matrix)
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It worked. The only part I didn't understand is ndim. What does that signify?

Comment: `ndim` = number of dimensions in the array, so in this case 2.  In the memoryview versions, the number of dimensions is indicated by the number of empty slices - `float64_t[:]` = 1 dim, `float64_t[:, :]` = 2 dim, etc.